# how can I make the array change each time it is iterated?

Tags: java, arrays

I have commented the question! I want it to say BMW first, then Hyundai and at the end Dodge.

```
    String[] [] cars = new String[3] [2];
    cars [0] [0] = "BMW";
    cars [0] [1] = "i7!";
    cars [1] [0] = "Hyundai";
    cars [1] [1] = "Tuscon!";
    cars [2] [0] = "Dodge";
    cars [2] [1] = "Challenger!";

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        StringBuilder sa = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < cars[i].length; j++) {
            if ( j == 0) {
                // what can I do to make the final statement (the name of manufacturer change for each time it is printed out, instead of i.e BMW for all of em
                sa.append ("The manufacturer " + cars1 [0] [0] ); sa.append (" has just published a video of ");
            } else {
                sa.append(" the model ");
            }
            sa.append(cars [i] [j]);
        }

        System.out.println(sa);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: change `cars1 [0] [0]` to `cars1 [i][j]`?

Comment: Don't use an array to store information about a Car. Define a Car class, with a field `manufacturer` and a field `model`. Then create an array of cars, and iterate over the array of cars. Java is an OO language. You're supposed to use objects.

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cars))`. This shuffles only in the first dimension of the array, so manufacturers and models are kept together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change:

`sa.append ("The manufacturer " + cars [0] [0] );`

into :

`sa.append ("The manufacturer " + cars [i] [j] );`

Comment: it worked, thanks a dozen.

Comment: Your welcome.
Be careful to the index of rows `i` and index of columns `j` when using two dimensions array.